# css nesting issue

Tags: html, css

I have a structure as

```
<div id ="page" class="item-page">
<table id="schedule">
</table>
</div>
```

How would i put in the styling information for #schedule

Would it be something like

```
#page .item-page #schedule{
 // css goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! It would be `#page.item-page #schedule { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#page.item-page #schedule{
 // css goes here
}
```

or just

```
#schedule{
 // css goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using id *and id must be unique per page, you can directly use that* instead:

```
#schedule{
 // css goes here
}
```

Comment: Seeing at some websites, I would say that they *should* be unique :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: You say: `id is unique per element per page`. But shouldn't `id` be unique on page period?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Only if one co-incidently uses same id name on different pages. In that case one would go with `#page #schedule`, however it is always a good idea to have unique names.

Comment: @Sarfraz: ??? The question is is it valid to have twe elements on a page with the same id

Comment: @PeeHaa: It is invalid markup to have two elements with same id. See id stands for identifier which must be unique. Think of it identity card :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: I know. Pfff I'm too drunk for this shit right now. I'll change your answer myself...

Answer (score 1):

Just `#page #schedule` would work fine.

In your code, `#page` and `.item-page` are the same element, so if you were to use both in your selector you would have to tie them together like this, `#page.item-page` rather than placing a space between them, which suggests the second is a child of the first.

So while `#page #schedule` represents this:

```
<div id="page" class="item-page">
  <table id="schedule"></table>
</div>
```

`#page .item-page #schedule` actually represents this:

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="item-page">
    <table id="schedule"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming you're not using ids over and over (you shouldn't be), you could just refer to your table without a nested selector:

```
#schedule {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few ways:

Simply:

```
#schedule {
}

ID Selector
#page #schedule {
}

div#page table#schedule {
}


Class Selector
.item-page #schedule {
}


div.item-page #schedule {
}


Both
div#page.item-selector table#schedule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/). and [inheritance](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/) In short, there is no reason to do be that specific.

CSS parses your rules from right to left, so here is what is going on at the browser level.

`#schedule` -> Browser says "Ok, anything with the ID "schedule", oh that's this table. Got it."

`.item-page #schedule` Browser says "Umm... got it, this table, when it exists inside anything with the class "item-page" that's... still just this browser.

`#page .item-page #schedule` Um.. so anything with the id "schedule" that's inside "item-page" that's inside "#page"... **Wait! That doesn't exist!**

```
#schedule{
    //css
}
```

would be more than sufficient.

If you want an example of inheritance:

```
.item-page table{}
```

will affect any table inside of .item-page

```
.item-page>table{}
```

will affect any table that is a DIRECT child of .item-page